# SQLAlchemy filtering for admin

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, decorator

I'm trying to maintain my code as simple as possible and I came across next problem:

First, we have several users, each has it's own records in database, that has his ID field. But when Admin is making a query I need to show him all records of all users.

All I want is to figure out if I can build a decorator, which would put **?**-sign or *-sign instead of **user_id** in the query OR modify the query in a fashion that it would show all records.

```
user_id = get_user_id_function()
query_result = session.query(Client).filter(operator == user_id).all()
```

But the problem is that if I put '?' or '*' - query won't show all records... And I don't want to turn to

```
if Admin:
    run this special query
else:
    run regular one
```

Is my challenge achievable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of a compromise.  Instead of having the query written twice, you just conditionally include the filter for non-admins.

```
# Psuedo code
admin_user_id = get_admin_user_id_function()
user_id = get_user_id_function()
client_query = session.query(Client)
if user_id != admin_user_id:
    client_query = client_query.filter(operator == user_id)
query_result = client_query.all()
```

As more AND filters are needed you can do something like this:

```
# Psuedo code
admin_user_id = get_admin_user_id_function()
user_id = get_user_id_function()
filter_args = []
if user_id != admin_user_id:
    filter_args.append(operator == user_id)
# conditionally include more filters here
# ...
query_result = session.query(Client).filter(*filter_args).all()
```